# Slow fuzzy search using PostgreSQL trigrams on long text fields

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, full-text-search

I'm seeing slow queries (~20 seconds) when I perform a fuzzy text search across a relatively small set of records (8k) in PostgreSQL. I've set up GIN and GIST trigram indexes, and confirmed via ANALYZE that they are being used. The performance appears to be driven by a small number of records that have very long text fields. While most records are under 2k characters, about 200 are over 10k, with a few over 20k. Truncating these long strings to 10k characters brings down the query time to 8s.

I've tried PostgreSQL 10 and 11, GIN and GIST indexes, with no substantial change in the performance.

I tried splitting up the text content into a larger number of records, with each record being a lot smaller. Searching this same text distributed across many more records results in sub-second queries.

The query is entirely unremarkable:

```sql
select title, 
'orthopedic surgeon' <<-> content as sml
from answers
where 'orthopedic surgeon' <% content
order by sml desc
```

With this small number of records, I'm expecting a trigram index to provide near-instant results, even if my text fields have 30k+ characters. I don't expect faster queries by splitting up the content across more records. Is this performance normal?

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this very late, obviously, but I was banging my head against a similar issue and your observation about better performance from splitting up the text made it click.

The trigram index works by looking for bits of your search string in the target documents. This part is super fast. So if you're searching for "gold star", it will immediately locate all the records that contain each of the trigrams "gol", "old", "ld ", "d s", " st", "sta", and "tar".

However, there's no guarantee that the trigrams are in the correct order. Maybe you have a record with the text "old star by golly" -- it has everything the index is looking for, but it doesn't actually contain "gold star" anywhere. So, having identified a set of candidate records, Postgres must now scan each candidate to verify that the desired text is actually present in the desired sequence. And this part is just a plain old text scan, slogging through the whole record until it finds the text (or doesn't).

Therefore, you want to make the first step of this process -- the index part -- do as much of the work as possible. If you have a 10,000-character record where your search string appears twice, and you don't split it up, then Postgres will have to scan (on average) 3,333 characters before it confirms that the substring is present. If you split it up into a hundred 100-character subrecords, the index will knock out ninety-eight of them, and Postgres only has to scan an average of 100 characters, speeding up the operation by a factor of 33.

(There's probably more to it than that -- I suspect there are optimizations in Postgres that only work up to a certain text length -- but this is surely part of it.)